# Inner join with navigation proprieties in entity framewrok

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 2 tables Blogs and Posts as following:

```
   public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public int Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}


  public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to return a blog object using inner join I used this:

```
var blog = blogPostContext.Blogs
    .Join(
        blogPostContext.Posts,
        blog => blog.BlogId,
        post => post.BlogId,
        (blog, post) => new { Blog = blog, Post = post })
    .Select(joinResult => joinResult.Blog)
    .ToList();
```

I want to recieve the blog including the posts but the previous query returns the posts as null, I can't use Include() because I want only inner join
Any solution?

Comment: You can make it without inner join just by filtering `blogPostContext.Blogs.Include( b => b.Posts).Where(x => x.Posts.Any()).ToList()`.

Comment: It would be kinda equal to left join with `where FK is not null` filtration, the same as inner join.

Comment: Actually you need `Include`. You have Eager Loading query which do not have direct translation to the SQL. `Include` for collection in `Single Query` variant uses LEFT JOINT to do not filer out Blog records. More explained here [Single vs. Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

Answer (score 0):

So your error is that you are selecting the same blog again. You preform the join you get a result combination of a single blog and a single post from which you only get the blog.

I tested with this inputs:

```
List<Blog> blogs = new List<Blog>()
{
    new Blog() { BlogId = 1, Url = "url 1", Posts = null },
    new Blog() { BlogId = 2, Url = "url 2", Posts = null }
};

List<Post> posts = new List<Post>()
{ 
    new Post() { PostId = 1, BlogId = 1, Title = 1, Content = "content 1", Blog = null },
    new Post() { PostId = 2, BlogId = 1, Title = 2, Content = "content 2", Blog = null }, 
    new Post() { PostId = 3, BlogId = 2, Title = 3, Content = "content 3", Blog = null },
};
```

Here is how you can modify your solution to get a list of blogs for each post while the blog contains the appropriate post. This is not the correct solution because you get duplicate blogs for different posts.

```
// There is a blog for each post containing only that post
var blogsForAllPosts = blogs.Join(posts,
b => b.BlogId,
p => p.BlogId,
//(b, p) => new { Blog = b, Post = p })
(b, p) => new Blog() 
{
    BlogId = b.BlogId,
    Url = b.Url,
    Posts = new List<Post> { p }
})
//.Select(x => x.Blog)
.ToList();
```

You can do more filtering and selecting on this result to get your desired output but that is bad for performance.

That being said.
Here is the easiest way to get your desired output:

```
// Number of blog stays the same, the posts of the blog are filled by querying the posts list by blog id
List<Blog> blogsWithPosts = blogs.Select(b => new Blog()
{
    BlogId = b.BlogId,
    Url = b.Url,
    Posts = posts.Where(p => p.BlogId == b.BlogId).ToList() 
}).ToList();
```

Another way to do the same thing with a join is the following:

```
// Multiple enumerables (variable blogPosts) of posts based on blogId which are the posts for those blogs
List<Blog> blogsWithPostsLinqJoin = (from blog in blogs
                                    join post in posts
                                    on blog.BlogId equals post.BlogId into blogPosts
                                    from bp in blogPosts
                                    select new Blog()
                                    {
                                        BlogId = blog.BlogId,
                                        Url = blog.Url,
                                        Posts = blogPosts.ToList()
                                    }).DistinctBy(b => b.BlogId).ToList();
```

But, since you tagged this question with entity-framework and you are getting your blogs and posts form a database context you should want to make full use of its features.

You need to add the foreign key data annotation to the BlogId property in your Post class.
And you need to make the property Blog a virtual property in your Post class.
And you need to make the property Posts a virtual property in your Blog class.

```
public class Post
[ForeignKey("Blog")]
public int BlogId { get; set; }
public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }

public class Blog   
public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
```

Then you can make use of the Include method of entity-framework on your blogs.

```
var blog = blogPostContext.Blogs.Include(b => b.Posts);
```

This should return all of your blogs along with their appropriate posts.

For more reading on entity-framework and how include work you can check out these tutorial links:

[Tutorial: Create a more complex data model for an ASP.NET MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application#create-instructor-entity)

[Tutorial: Read related data with EF in an ASP.NET MVC app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)